# How to set different rules for different collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I want my application read only the language collection data from firebase before authentication
only and read data from Users collection only when user is authenticated. [image]

my rules
[image]

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both. Also: please include your rules as text rather than a screenshot, so that folks can easily use your existing rules when answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're asking for:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Language/{document} {
      allow read: if true;
    }
    match /Users/{document} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

With the above any user (regardless of their authentication state) can read the `Language` collection, but only authenticated users can read the `Users` collection.